# What is the filming location of the Mercian mausoleum in "The Profit and the Loss"?

Tags: film-location, vikings

In the *Vikings* episode ["The Profit and the Loss"](http://vikings.wikia.com/wiki/The_Profit_and_the_Loss) King Ecbert meets Prince Wicksten in a royal Mercian mausoleum. What real-world location(s) were used when filming the exterior and interior? Or were they sets?

[image: Close shot of the exterior of the burial mound]

[image: Interior shot]